# How to clone struct with a mutable reference

Tags: rust

I have a struct containing a mutable reference (`MyStruct2`) that I need to clone, so I derived the `Clone` method for that struct:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    val: usize,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct2<'a> {
    struct_reference: &'a mut MyStruct
}
```

However, when I compile this code, I get the following error message:

```
src/main.rs:419:3: 419:37 error: the trait `core::clone::Clone` is not implemented for the type `&mut MyStruct` [E0277]
src/main.rs:419         struct_reference: &'a mut MyStruct
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:417:11: 417:16 note: in this expansion of #[derive_Clone] (defined in src/main.rs)
src/main.rs:419:3: 419:37 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:419:3: 419:37 help: the following implementations were found:
src/main.rs:419:3: 419:37 help:   <MyStruct as core::clone::Clone>
src/main.rs:419:3: 419:37 note: required by `core::clone::Clone::clone`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

If I make the reference immutable, then the code compiles.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    val: usize,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct2<'a> {
    struct_reference: &'a MyStruct
}
```

It seems that even though clone is derived for the struct `MyStruct`, it is not derived for a mutable reference to `MyStruct`.

Is there a way to clone a mutable reference to a struct and to clone a struct containing a mutable reference?

Comment: I would suggest that you re-read [*The Rust Programming Language* chapter on references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules). It is *vitally* important that you understand the restriction on mutable aliasing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to have [multiple non-mutable references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules) to the same resource. So in the code which compiles, you will get two references to the same `MyStruct` when `MyStruct2` is cloned.:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    val: usize,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct2<'a> {
    struct_reference: &'a MyStruct
}
```

However, it is only possible to have a single mutable reference to a resource. So it is not possible to automatically implement `Clone` for `MyStruct2`. You can implement it yourself, it will look like this:

```
impl<'a> Clone for MyStruct2<'a> {
    fn clone(&self) -> MyStruct2<'a> {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

But you still can't have two mutable references to the same `MyStruct`. 
You also can't create a clone of `MyStruct` which lives long enough to return in the clone function. So you would have to modify your data structure to make this possible.